# CSS Media Query - Device width - portrait vs landscape

Tags: css, width, orientation, media-queries

I have following doubts:

1) Does the device-width that a media query matches, change depending on the mode (portrait vs landscape)?

2) Do usual laptops and desktops ever match portrait mode? Is the orientation random/undefined for devices that do not have screen rotation? Or does it always logically correspond to portrait (if height < width)  and landscape (width < height).

regards

JP

Answer (score 4):

**1)** *Well*, Yes it does in most cases, consider following example:

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 400px) {
    // styles here
}
```

Now your styles are applied only when the screen is `400px` wide or less. Whether the device is in *portrait* or *landscape* mode does **not** matter.

**But** in iOS, there's a problem. There the device width is always `320px` (iPhone) or, `768px` for the iPad. So you need to use the `orientation` media *query*, otherwise or you won’t be able to tell that the user has changed orientation.

**2)** laptops and desktops match `landscape` mode as default *(but you can change the orientation mode of browser [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236245/is-it-possible-to-emulate-orientation-in-a-browser))*. Since the use-case of `orientation` is on the iOS, you can be sure there's no *random/undefined* orientation.

Here is a nice tool for CSS3 media query: http://cssmediaqueries.com/

For more reading:

- http://blog.cloudfour.com/ipad-orientation-css/
- http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/01/device-width-and-how-not-to-hate-your.html
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using  min or max width. Using device layout can cause issues as there are hundreds of thousands of devices, each with a slightly different resolution.

As far as i know, computers do not render a layout mode.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
//styles
}

@media screen and (min-width: 420px) {
//styles
}
```

It is best to use a mobile first method when using media queries (min-width) where each width element adds rules to a style. This will prevent duplicate rules and over writing. It also allows graceful browser fallback for older browsers.